# the land_on method does not work when outputting data, it shows leading values (the interpreter does not see the error)

Tags: python

```py
class CanFly:
    def __init__(self):
        self.altitude = 0
        self.velocity = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} название {} высота, {} скорость '.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.altitude, self.velocity)

class ButterFly(CanFly):

    def take_off(self):
        self.altitude = 1

    def fly(self):
        self.velocity = 0.1

    def land_on(self):
        self.altitude = 0
        self.velocity = 0


butter = ButterFly()
print(butter)
butter.take_off()
print(butter)
butter.fly()
print(butter)
butter.land_on
print(butter)
```

I tried to move the method to the canfly class. Didn't help (obviously)

Comment: You need to call the method `land_on()`. You meant to write this: `butter.land_on()`.